# Problems with List estructure JPA

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working in a project using spring Boot with JPA and im getting an issue with the findAll method, especially with the structure.

```
[
  {
    "idProducto": 5,
    "nombreProducto": "Perfil madera 2",
    "codProducto": 556,
    "proveedorProducto": {
      "idProveedor": 1,
      "rubro": "Maderas y tallados",
      "codProveedor": 2556
    },
    "tipoProducto": {
      "idTipoPro": 2,
      "descProducto": "Maderas"
    },
    "inventarioProducto": {
      "idInventario": 5,
      "stockInicial": 990,
      "stockCritico": 200,
      "fechaVencimiento": "2100-04-23",
      "precioVentaInv": 20000,
      "precioCompraInv": 10000,
      "fechaIngreso": "2018-04-23",
      "producto": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "idProducto": 6,
    "nombreProducto": "Perfil madera 4inch",
    "codProducto": 555,
    "proveedorProducto": 1,
    "tipoProducto": 2,
    "inventarioProducto": {
      "idInventario": 6,
      "stockInicial": 9997,
      "stockCritico": 200,
      "fechaVencimiento": "2100-04-23",
      "precioVentaInv": 25000,
      "precioCompraInv": 12000,
      "fechaIngreso": "2018-04-23",
      "producto": 6
    }
  }
]
```

as you can see the first product have the right structure, but in the second the problem is with the "tipoProducto" Object and "productoProveedor" Object, of which I only get its id's, and i don't know why im getting this results.

this is my class structure:

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @NotNull
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "pro_id_producto")
  private int idProducto;
  @NotNull
  @Size(max = 45, message = "Máximo de 45")
  @Column(name = "pro_nombre_producto")
  private String nombreProducto;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "pro_codigo_producto")
  private int codProducto;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "pro_us_id_proveedor", referencedColumnName = "us_id_persona")
  private Proveedor proveedorProducto;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "pro_tp_id_tipo_producto", referencedColumnName = "pro_id_tipo_producto")
  private TipoProducto tipoProducto;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "producto",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Inventario inventarioProducto;
// getters and setters omited
```

this is my repo:

```
@Repository
public interface   ProductoRepository extends JpaRepository<Producto,Integer> {
  Producto getByCodProducto(int codPro);
  Boolean existsByCodProducto(int codPro);

}
```

and this is my service layer:

```
@Service
public class ProductoService {
  @Autowired
  private ProductoRepository productoRepository;

  public List<Producto> getAllProductos(){
   return productoRepository.findAll();
  }

  public Producto getProducto(int idPro)throws EntityNotFoundException{
    Producto producto = productoRepository.getOne(idPro);
    if (producto == null){
      throw  new EntityNotFoundException(Producto.class,"idProducto", Integer.toString(idPro));
    }
    return producto;
  }
  public void saveProducto(Producto producto){
    productoRepository.save(producto);
  }
  public Producto getProductoByCod(int codPro) throws  EntityNotFoundException{
    Producto producto = productoRepository.getByCodProducto(codPro);
    if (producto == null){
      throw new EntityNotFoundException(Producto.class,"codProducto", Integer.toString(codPro));
    }
    return producto;
  }
  public boolean deleteProducto(int id)throws EntityNotFoundException{
    Producto producto = productoRepository.getOne(id);
    if (producto == null){
      throw  new EntityNotFoundException(Producto.class,"idProducto",Integer.toString(id));
    }else {
      productoRepository.deleteById(id);
      return true;
    }
  }
  public boolean existeProducto(int cod){
    return productoRepository.existsByCodProducto(cod);
  }
```

i don't if it's problem with the mapping or something else. any help would be great. because i've being looking everywhere for an answer.
P.S: i'm a newbie in this world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is reproduced because when you put fetch type to Lazy Hibernate won't take it strongly persisted. So you need to change to Eager which will be loaded all of the relationships related to a particular object.

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
```